# Evaluate Arithmetic String Produces Arithmetic overflow error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

First off,  we are on Azure SQL DB (now that's said).

We have a calculations table that stores math strings.
I'm attempting to get answers from math strings by running them through Exec command.

Simple example `EXEC ('select ' + '500*5000')`  works fine.

`EXEC ('select ' + '7500000*10000000000')` also works fine.

However

`EXEC ('select ' + '75000*1000000')` produces Arithmetic overflow error

Huh?
Doesn't the second example also result in a bigint?  Why is that one ok?

From what I can tell, there is a background process to dynamically determine the size of the resulting data type.  In any case, we need to make sure no calculations error out due to overflow.

My question is how can I force bigint on any evaluation?

I've tried

`EXEC ('select cast(' + '750000*1000000' + 'as bigint)')`

and

`EXEC ('select convert(bigint,' + '750000*1000000' + ')')`

Alternatively, is there a setting we can tweak to tell the server to use bigint by default in evaluations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to carry out your `cast`/`convert` to a component of the calculation *before* you carry out your computation, not after, because SQL Server returns the result of the largest component of the calculation which is why it worked when one of the components provided was already a bigint. e.g.

```
EXEC ('select ' + '750000*cast(1000000 as bigint)')

-- or

EXEC ('select ' + '750000*convert(bigint,1000000)')
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: "SQL Server returns the result of the largest component of the calculation which is why it worked when one of the components provided was already a bigint"  

I didn't know that.  makes sense.  This does give me a direction to go towards.  Thanks!